# pip always fails ssl verification

Tags: ssl, pip

Pip always fails ssl even when I do `pip install dedupe` or `pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org dedupe`

The output is always the same no matter what:

> Collecting dedupe
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/dedupe/
>   Retrying...
>
> skipping
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dedupe (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for dedupe

So I uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it. Same thing.

Do you think the problem is that my _ssl.c file (which I have no idea where it is) must be corrupt or something? Why would pip need to reference that if I'm telling it to bypass ssl verification anyway?

Comment: seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c?noredirect=1&lq=1 but I'm on a windows machine

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It may be related to the [2018 change](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/03/warehouse-all-new-pypi-is-now-in-beta.html) of PyPI [domains](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5288#issuecomment-383071739).
Please ensure your firewall/proxy allows access to/from:

- *pypi.org*
- *files.pythonhosted.org*

So you could give a try to something like:

> $ python -m pip `install` --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org [--proxy ...] [--user] `<packagename>`

Please see `$ pip help install` for the `--user` option description (omit if in a virtualenv).
The `--trusted-host` option doesn't actually bypass SSL/TLS, but allows to mark host as trusted when (and only when) it does not have valid (or any) HTTPS. It shouldn't really matter with PiPY because pypi.org (formerly pypi.python.org) *does* use HTTPS and there is CDN in front of it which always enforces TLSv1.2 handshake requirement regardless of the connecting pip client options.. But if you had your own local mirrors of pypi.org with HTTP-only access, then `--trusted-host` could be handy. Oh, and if you are behind a proxy, please also make sure to also specify: `--proxy [user:passwd@]proxyserver:port`
Some corporate proxies may even go as far as to [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846652/can-proxy-change-ssl-certificate) the certificates of HTTPS connections on the fly. And if your system clock is out of sync, it could break SSL verification process as well.

If firewall / proxy / clock isn't a problem, then check SSL certificates being used in pip's SSL handshake. In fact, you could just get a current [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) (Mozilla's CA bundle from [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)) and try it using the pip option `--cert`:

> `$ pip --cert ~/cacert.pem install --user <packagename>`
>   where `--cert` argument is system path to your alternate CA bundle in PEM format. (regarding the --user option, please see below).
>   Or, it's possible to create a custom config ~/.pip/pip.conf and point the option at a valid system cert (or your cacert.pem) as a workaround, for example:
>   *[global]*
>   *cert = /etc/pki/tls/external-roots/ca_bundle.pem*
>   (or another pem file)

It's even possible to manually replace the original cacert.pem found in pip with your trusty CA bundle (if your pip is very old for example). Older pip versions knew to fallback between pip/_vendor/requests/cacert.pem and system stores like `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` or `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` in case of cert issues, but in recent pip it's no longer the case, as it seems to rely solely on pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem

Basically, pip package uses `requests` which uses `urllib3` which, among other things, verifies SSL certificates; and all of them are shipped (vendored) within pip, along with the `certifi` package (also included, since pip 9.0.2) that provides current CA bundle (cacert.pem file) required for TLS verification. Requests itself uses urllib3 and certifi internally, and before 9.0.2, pip used cacert.pem from requests or the system. What it all means is that actually updating pip may help fix the CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error, particularly if the OS and pip were deployed long ago:

- The OP used anaconda, so they could try:
  `$ conda update pip` - because [issues can arise](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) if conda and `pip`  are both used together in the same environment. If there's no pip version update available, they could try:
  `$ conda config --add channels conda-forge; conda update pip`
  Alternatively, it's possible to use [conda](https://conda.io/en/latest/) alone to directly install / manage python packages: it is a tool completely separate from pip, but provides similar features in terms of package and venv management. Its packages come not from PyPI, but from [anaconda's own repositories](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/). 
  The problem is, if you mix both and run conda after `pip`, the former can overwrite and break packages (and their dependencies) installed via pip, and render it all unusable. So it's recommended to *only use one or the other*, or, if you have to, use *only pip after* conda (and no conda after pip), and only in isolated conda environments.
- On normal Linux Python installations without conda:
  If you are using a version of pip supplied by your OS distribution, then use vendor-supplied upgrades for a system-wide pip update:
  `$ sudo apt-get install python-pip`  or:  `$ sudo yum install python27-pip`
  Some updates may not be readily available because distros usually lag behind PyPI. In this case, it's possible to upgrade pip at your **user level** (right in your *$HOME* dir), or inside a virtualenv, like:
  `$ python -m pip install --user --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --upgrade pip`
  (omit `--user` if in a virtualenv)
  The `--user` switch will upgrade pip only for the current user (in your home ~/.local/lib/) rather than for the whole OS, which is a good practice to avoid interfering with the system python packages. It's enabled by default in a pip distributed in recent Ubuntu/Fedora versions. Be aware of how to solve [ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964093/file-usr-bin-pip-line-9-in-module-from-pip-import-main-importerror-canno/) if you don't use this option and happen to overwrite the OS-level system pip.
  Alternatively (also at a user level) you could try:
  `$ curl -LO https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python get-pip.py --user`
  The PyPA [script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) contains a wrapper that extracts the .pem SSL bundle from pip._vendor.certifi.

Otherwise, if still no-go, try running pip with `-vvv` option to add verbosity to the output and check if there is now another `SSLError` caused by [tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646558).

Comment: I suggest creating this alias in your .bash_profile or .zshrc to make it easier:
`alias pp="python -m pip install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org "`

Comment: @henry  Hey, yeah, indeed, or in ~/.bashrc and then `source` it.. Although, it may be a good idea to try and update `pip` and see if it fixes the root cause of the certificates problem. Or one could just get current Mozilla [CA bundle file](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and use it with pip option `--cert` (answer updated).

Comment: I am not having success with any of the approaches suggested in this post thus far. Even though I specify pypi.org, pypi.python.org and files.pythonhosted.org as trusted hosts, I get error "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443)". Why is it trying to confirm an ssl certificate if I've specified those hosts as trusted?

Comment: The options you have given (for example in my case: 'python -m pip install --user --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn tensorflow pickle --upgrade pip') worked like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 50):

This worked for me, try this:

`pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user {name of whatever I'm installing}`

Comment: Works for Forcepoint SSL issues also !

Answer (score 36):

I experienced the same issue because I have **Zscaler** (a cloud security software) installed and was causing:

- URL host for python packages being blocked
- invalid SSL certificate warnings popping up
- SSL inspection certificate not trusted

As mentioned by others, the below will fix individual package installations. `pypi.python.org` is not required since it has been replaced by `pypi.org`.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package to install>
```

I permanently fixed the issue by creating `pip.ini` file (`pip.conf` in Unix) and adding the below:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

See [pip configuration files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/) for how to locate your `pip.ini`, or where to put it if you need to create one.

Comment: I had Global protect which was blocking the requests.

Comment: I believe this answer is underrated. We are also repressed by Zscaler by our IT and this solution has saved a lot of headaches.

Comment: Me too another Zscaler victim..., this solved a lot of time.

Comment: I had same issue due to Zcaler, and this solution worked. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: I wonder where's the security if a software that is supposed to give you additional security, Zscaler, forces you to disable certificate checks in order to do your daily job. We are losing control of IT. Actually, IT is losing control of IT.

Comment: I was using Zscaler and had this issue. What fixed for me was "pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user [package name]"

Comment: This solution is **insecure**, you should instead configure proper trusted CA certificates to be used by pip. See ZScaler's help page for doing this for pip (and other applications): https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trust-store#pip

Answer (score 18):

My way is a simplification of @Alex C's answer:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip
```

Comment: No matter that I specify these trusted hosts, my attempts to install always result in "There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443)". So it seems that SSL confirmation is always attempted, no matter what.

Comment: You might be under a firewall without knowing it, for example, because of restrictions on a work laptop.

Comment: @Tomasso See my answer below to resolve the issue permanently.

Comment: only this of the above worked for me

Answer (score 5):

The error above or one like it was caused by the virtual machine (VM) not be time synchronized, my guest Ubuntu VM was several days in the past.

I ran this commend to get the VM to pick up the correct network time:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```

This makes the Ubuntu guest OS get the network time. (You may have to provide a network time source... I used this article: [Digital Ocean - How to set time on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-16-04))

Check the time is correct:

```
timedatectl
```

Re-run the failing pip command.

Comment: lmao, I forgot this, oh god :)

Answer (score 2):

**For those using macOS:**

The issue is that Python 3.6+ is no longer using macOS's OpenSSL, but rather its own bundled OpenSSL which doesn't have access to macOS's root certificates. Here’s the permanent fix.

First run these commands:

```bash
# Update pip
pip3 --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org install --upgrade pip
# Install certifi
pip3 --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org install certifi
```

Add this to your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.zprofile` or whatever startup file your shell uses), so that your environment knows where to find the certifi CA bundle:

```bash
if [ -x "$(command -v python3)" ]; then
    # Side note: 'python3 -m certifi' is also equivalent to
    # 'python3 -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"'                                                                                             
    export SSL_CERT_FILE="$(python3 -m certifi)"
    export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="${SSL_CERT_FILE}"
fi
```

Restart your shell, or re-source your shell startup file:

```bash
. ~/.bash_profile
```

pip3 (or any Python script making HTTPS requests) should now work without using a long pip3 command or dangerously disabling certificate verification.

<sup>Side note: You may notice that I didn’t include pypi.python.org as a trusted host. This is because it has been deprecated since 2018. I haven’t included it for over a year now, and I’ve never had an issue. As far as I know, it’s now unused.</sup>