# failed to install packages in pycharm and also using command prompt error "could not find a version"

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, windows-10, package

I am not able to install any packages with Pycharm professional 2019 (Windowns 10, 64bits).

It always generates the same error «**Non-zero exit code (1)
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests**
.And it also tells to check the *pip* version installed for Python. My *pip* version is "pip 19.0.3" with Python-3.7.4

Below screenshot shows the error which occures within Pycharm
[Error in pycharm][1]. Using the [command prompt results in the almost same error][2]

I also tried to change the respository to https://pypi.python.org/pypi but it did not help either.

I try this .but still getting error

```
C:\>pip --proxy=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org install requests
Collecting requests
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022BB22A0D88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022BB22C1988>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022BB22C1888>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022BB22CBA08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022BB22C1DC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/requests/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```

And also this also

```````````````````````````
C:\>pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD172C248>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD1728D08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD1728C08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD1728CC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD17106C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/requests/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests
``````````````````````````



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcgjN.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/haNxX.png
```````````````````````````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fail with SSL certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:833)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960583/pip-install-fail-with-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c833)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be due to proxy or firewall settings at your end. Please check your proxy settings

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.