# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-airflow (from version: none)

Tags: pip, airflow, python-3.7, python-venv

I am currently trying to run 'pip install -r requirements.txt' from VS Code to install some packages (including Apache Airflow). I used the command 'pip install -r requirements.txt'; however I am receiving the following error message:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/apache-airflow/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(hos=pypi.org', port =443): Max Retries with 
url: /simple/apache-airflow (Caused by 
SSLError(SsLCertVerificationError(1, '['SSL: CERTIFICATE VERIFY 
FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer 
certificate(_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
apache-airflow==1.10.15 (from version: none)

ERROR: NO matching distribution found for apache_airflow==1.10.15 
(from requirements.txt(line 1))
```

I have tried the following as well:

```
export AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.15
```

I have also confirmed that my current version of Python is 3.7.10 and my current version of PIP is 20.1.1...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anything else to the error message? What happens when you download the whl manually and try to install that? What is your OS and do you have 32 or 64 bit python?

Comment: Hey @FlyingTeller, thanks for responding. I've updated the question but the error thjat I am also seeing is: "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/apache-airflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(hos=pypi.org', port =443): Max Retries with url: /simple/apache-airflow (Caused by SSLError(SsLCertVerificationError(1, '['SSL: CERTIFICATE VERIFY FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate(_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping

Comment: 64 bit on windows 10 (VDI) - btw

Comment: Ah, the rest of the error message was kind of important. Are you behind a proxy maybe? Have you tried the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960583/pip-install-fail-with-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c833)?