# unable to install Django in win 10

Tags: django, pip

I am trying to install Django in windows 10 through - pip install django command but getting the error -- " -- "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping". I have tried using the proxy server also but none worked. ". I have tried installing using the proxy also but none worked.

Comment: hi can you give more details of your issue, show ur error log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip always fails ssl verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324802/pip-always-fails-ssl-verification)

Comment: Hi grey,
See, first I have created one virtual environment and then through command prompt I was trying to install Django (command - pip install Django). Then getting the error - that there was a problem confirming the ssl certificates.