# Installing Tensorflow 1.9 in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in Windows,

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

The error I got is

> Collecting protobuf>=3.4.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0)   Could not find a
>   version that satisfies the requirement protobuf>=3.4.0 (from
>   tensorflow==1.9.0) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for protobuf>=3.4.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0)

I googled online and I couldn't find any solutions. I am using python 3.5 64 bit

Comment: This question is very vague. Did you follow the steps listed 
 [on the Tensowflow page?](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) At which point does the process fail? Google that error. The more specific the error, the better the results will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed python 3.5.4 and tried to install tensorflow but then pip started showing SSL certificate error. Googling online gave me a stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324802/pip-always-fails-ssl-verification).

The command that worked for me is

```
python -m pip install tensorflow --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Anaconda
Create a new environment or activate your existing environment

```
conda create -n Tensorflow_Environment python=3.6
activate Tensorflow_Environment
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.9.0
```

You could refer [Tensorflow Install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) for GPU version Installation