# How to install version of tensorflow that isn't available through pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am attempting to install a specific version of tensorflow as part of the requirements for some code I'm trying to use (https://github.com/serengil/deepface)

When I attempt to install it like I normally do in command prompt I get the following.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install tensorflow==1.9.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.9.0 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.9.0
```

I have referenced a few other Stackoverflow questions ([Installing Tensorflow 1.9 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401181/installing-tensorflow-1-9-in-windows/51402431)) and haven't been able to find a solution or how to go about getting the version needed.

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflow==1.9.0` is available on PyPI ([link](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.9.0/)). Your issue is that you are probably using Python 3.7, which 1.9.0 doesn't support, only Python 2.7 and 3.3 to 3.6. Install 64bit Python 3.6 and use it instead of 3.7.