# I have a mistake for the installation of Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssl, ssl-certificate

When I try to install matplotlib with the command `pip install matplotlib`
I have this erreur :

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/matplotlib/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/matplotlib/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

I use python 3.9.5 64-bit, pip 21.1.2 and I use a Macbook M1 (I don't know if it's important). I have to use matplotlib for my science class and I don't understand this mistake.
thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user matplotlib`

That problem is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991986/15487762).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
pip install matplotlib --trusted-host pypi.org
```