# Installing SSL CA certificates for docker container on Windows

Tags: python, docker, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to make a https request from within a docker container. Here's python code that runs fine on my Windows 10 host:

```py
import certifi
import ssl
import urllib.request


tmp_filename = "penguin.jpg"
pingu_link = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/3a/1a/cc3a1ae4beafdd5ac2293824f1fb0437.jpg"

print(certifi.where())
default = ssl.create_default_context()
https_handler = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl.create_default_context())
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(https_handler)
# add user agent headers to avoid 403 response
opener.addheaders = [
    (
        "User-agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0",
    )]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
r = urllib.request.urlretrieve(pingu_link, tmp_filename)
```

If I understand correctly, certifi comes with its own set of CA certificates, which are contained in the .pem file you can find by calling `certifi.where()`. However, if I convert this file to .crt and tell request to use it by calling

```
https_handler = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl.create_default_context(cafile="cacert.crt"))
```

the verification fails: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129). As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422136/python-requests-with-wincertstore) explains, certifi also automatically imports certfiles from windows cert store.
Now I'm a little confused what this means if you want to verify SSL certificates in a docker container. It seems like there are two options:

- Just install the `ca-certificates` package. It should provide the necessary public keys for most CAs.
- Install your own (possibly self-signed) certificate: copy it into your docker container and tell the ca-certificates package about it by calling `update-ca-certificates`. (You could also install it in windows global certificate store and it should work with docker out of the box according to [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21189#issuecomment-288694477) on github)

Unfortunately, the first approach does not seem to work for me. It raises the same Verification Error as above. Even worse, since I don't know which .crt file is used to verify certificates without docker, the second option is not a possibility either. Here's the Dockerfile:

```sh
# start with a python env that already has urllib3 installed
FROM company_harbor/base_py3_container 

ENV HTTP_PROXY="my_company_proxy"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY="my_company_proxy"
# install ca certificates
RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install ca-certificates -y && \
    apt-get clean

RUN pip install --upgrade certifi --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
# what I would do if I found the right .crt file
# COPY cacert.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.crt
# RUN chmod 644 /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
COPY ./download_penguin.py ./download_penguin.py

CMD [ "python", "download_penguin.py" ]
```

What do you need to do in order to verify SSL certificates with python in docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out company proxies can swap SSL certificates in a [Man-in-the-middle manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846652/can-proxy-change-ssl-certificate).
The standard certificates from `apt-get install ca-certificates` or python's certifi package are not going to include these company certificates. Additionally, this is not specifically a Docker related question but a question of "How to install a root certificate on Linux". Debian to be more precise, because thats what Docker containers run by default.

This was not as straight-forward as expected. Here's what worked in the end:

1. Use the company's certificates in **.pem** format to begin with.
2. Rename them so they end with .crt. Do NOT use any openssl .pem to .crt transformation. In my case, every .crt file I found online was encoded in a way that made it unreadable for Notepad++, Vim and alike. .pem files on the other hand looked fine.
3. Copy the renamed certificates to the proper ca-certificate location on your OS.
4. Install the certificates via `update-ca-certificates`.

Translated into a Dockerfile, here's the important part:

```
COPY root.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.crt
COPY proxy.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/proxy.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
```